# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE Crash in 32 bit devices

Tags: ios, swift

I began experiencing the following crash recently.

Crashed: com.socketio.engineHandleQueue
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE 0x0000000016500ade0

It seems to only affect to users with 32 bit devices.

When running the code to a 32 bit device the code crashes inside the socket operation queue.

```
Thread 7 Queue : com.socketio.engineHandleQueue (serial)

#0  0x014c3a00 in 0x014c3a00 ()
#1  0x00e16f70 in SingletonMetadata ()
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems related to [an bug with the Swift compiler optimization for 32 bit devices](https://forums.swift.org/t/crashes-on-32-bit-after-xcode-11-4/35035).

I was able to fix it by changing the Swift compiler optimization level from -O to -Onone.

**Update**

Tested with Xcode version 11.5 and fixes this problem.

Comment: Thank you! This saved my butt!! I so wish Apple would actually test their crap more. A bug like this is unacceptable on every level.

Comment: So upgrading to Xcode 11.5 beta or downgrading to 11.3.1 fixes issue for me